# reinstalling ubuntu on grub dual boot (with windows 10 and ubuntu), but ubuntu won't boot

Tags: 18.04, grub2, dpkg

I've tried using the default "Advanced options for Ubuntu" option in recovery mode, and used dpkg and fsck to try and repair it, but they both fail.

Is there a way to reinstall ubuntu using the windows interface?

Comment: No. You have to boot the live installer from UEFI boot menu & Something Else option to choose same partitions. (Assuming Windows is UEFI.) If you do not have backups you can do a "dirty" install where you do not reformat partition. Your files will still be ther, but any default system or user configuration files will be overwritten with default from install. System settings or anything in / may be overwritten with defaults. Good backups still important
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941872

Comment: What do I do if my windows is legacy, and not UEFI?

Comment: Its still the same boot from live installer. But if newer system since about 2012 Windows should be UEFI. If BIOS just be sure to boot live installer in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode, not UEFI. Disadvantage of BIOS is you only can have one boot loader in MBR and that must then be grub to dual boot. And grub only boots working Windows, so may need Windows repair disk if Windows needs chkdsk or turns fast start up back on with an update.